# Why do I need to connect servos to the ground of the battery and the ground of the RPi?

Tags: gpio, pi-2, electronics, servo

I'm trying to use two servos simultaneously and I've connected both servos to my battery pack which gives 6V (the servos require 6v). If I ground the servo only to the battery and I only use one of them it works fine. If I want to use both, the servos just stop and one of them sometimes moves a little bit. I noticed that if I wire it also to the ground of the RPi (with a 1k Ohm resistor between) it works fine. I can use both of them simultaneously.
So why do I need two groundings to work fine? Can't the single grounding handle both of the PWM outputs from the Pi or something in that direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a circuit for electricity to flow from the Pi to the servos and then back to the PI.

You control servos by sending 1-2 ms pulses along the control wire at 50-60 Hz.

If you don't have a ground wire between the servos and the Pi there is no circuit for the pulses.

Comment: So it's not possible to use another ground like the grounding of the battery pack? Why did it work with a single servo?

Comment: The battery pack -ve is connected to the servo ground.  They are equivalent.  Connect either the battery pack -ve or the servo ground to a Pi ground.  The answer I gave was overly simplistic.  The ground is a common reference point for the the voltages.  It might work without a common ground but it will not be reliable.

Comment: Can you explain to me why it is that way or link me to a source?

Comment: The best I can do is point to a post http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/90580/why-connect-two-power-supply-grounds